# Skip Authentication on An Active Admin Controller Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, activeadmin

I'm trying to allow an Arduino to post data to my Rails App periodically through params in a URL. I want the controller action that handles this to skip authentication so that I don't have to worry about auth on the Arduino. My controller is here:

```
controller do
    skip_before_filter :authenticate_admin_user!
    def capture_data
        new_record = BoxHouseDataLog.new
        new_record.box_number = params[:box_number]
        new_record.run_time_hours = params[:run_time_hours]
        new_record.run_time_minutes = params[:run_time_minutes]
        new_record.run_time_seconds = params[:run_time_seconds]
        new_record.air_temp = params[:air_temp]
        new_record.loop_temp = params[:loop_temp]
        new_record.rh = params[:rh]
        new_record.co2 = params[:co2]
        new_record.o2 = params[:o2]
        new_record.air_temp_setpoint = params[:air_temp_setpoint]
        new_record.loop_temp_setpoint = [:loop_temp_setpoint]
        new_record.rh_setpoint = params[:rh_setpoint]
        new_record.co2_setpoint = params[:co2_setpoint]
        new_record.save
    end
end
```

In my /config/initializers/active_admin.rb file:

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
config.skip_before_filter :authenticate_admin_user!
```

When I try to make the request I get a 401 Unauthorized Error and get redirected to create a new session with Devise.

Update:
Here are the logs...

> Started GET
>   "/capture_data?box_number=1&run_time_hours=111&run_time_minutes=11&run_time_seconds=11&air_temp=111.11&loop_temp=111.11&rh=111.11&co2=111.11&o2=111.11&air_temp_setpoint=111.11&loop_temp_setpoint=111.11&rh_setpoint=111.11&co2_setpoint=111.11&method=post"
>   for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-10 11:21:44 -0400 Processing by
>   Admin::BoxHouseDataLogsController#capture_data as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"box_number"=>"1", "run_time_hours"=>"111", "run_time_minutes"=>"11",
>   "run_time_seconds"=>"11", "air_temp"=>"111.11", "loop_temp"=>"111.11",
>   "rh"=>"111.11", "co2"=>"111.11", "o2"=>"111.11",
>   "air_temp_setpoint"=>"111.11", "loop_temp_setpoint"=>"111.11",
>   "rh_setpoint"=>"111.11", "co2_setpoint"=>"111.11", "method"=>"post"}
>   Completed 401 Unauthorized in 4.0ms
>
> Started GET "/admin/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-10 11:21:44 -0400
>   Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
>   DEPRECATION WARNING: f.buttons is deprecated in favour of f.actions.
>   (called from buttons at
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-b41450a52c09/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:119)
>   DEPRECATION WARNING: f.commit_button is deprecated in favour of
>   f.action(:submit). (called from commit_button at
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-b41450a52c09/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb:99)
>   Rendered active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within
>   layouts/active_admin_logged_out (77.3ms) Completed 200 OK in 302.5ms
>   (Views: 120.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: can you post your logs?

Comment: @Mandeep they don't seem to give any information towards the problem. Maybe I'm missing something though?